# Non repeating array number (which is added twice or more with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I know the question about obtaining a random number with javascript (non repeating) is often asked but in my case I append the same jquery code twice or three time and I would like to obtain different information each time.

First i have a large array (150 items) which is built this way :

```
var arr = [
{
    "Numéro": "1",
    "Chinois": "爱",
    "Pinyin": "ài",
    "Français": "aimer, affection, apprécier",
    "Classificateurs": ""
},
```

Then I found on another post this random function :

```
while(arr.length < 150){
    var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*147)
    var found=false;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
    }
    if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
}
```

Then I append the array information (I tried randomly - It's a flashcard kind of page so on click, the next "index" should be randomized and unique) on the page :

```
    $('#qcm-az, .suivantQcm1').on ('click', function(qcmaz){
    $('#reponse1').html(arr[index].Français);
    $('#reponse2').html(arr[147 -Math.floor((Math.random() * 23)+1)].Français);
    $('#reponse3').html(arr[99 - Math.floor((Math.random() * 65)+1)].Français);
    $('#reponse4').html(arr[43 - Math.floor((Math.random() * 21)+1)].Français);

    index = randomnumber;
});
```

So basically on page load or (if the next arrow is clicked) I would like the "index = randomnumber" to be ran once again but it seems stuck (because the random number seems allocated once and for all).

Finally you can see that, on my different divs, I'm using a not so random function to get a different index number. I often encounter a problem which is that the "good answer" (reponse1) is the same as in one of the "wrong answer" (reponse2,3 or 4).

I hope I explained myself clearly - I'm beginning in Javascript/Jquery. Thank you in advance.

**Edit : I added a fiddle to show you the problem (just click on the body to move to next item - which is stuck after one click here)**

http://jsfiddle.net/Hv8SD/

Comment: It sounds like you are reloading the page, is that correct? If that is true your JavaScript variables will be cleared. So it will just be a random item again, not a random and unique. An example at jsfiddle.net may be helpful.

Comment: I guess you are reading one by one the items of your shuffled array. Which is fine. You have yet to have three distinct (and !== index) random numbers between 0 and 149 items on each click. So make a little function that does just that (quite similar to the shuffling function) and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I made a fiddle because i'm little bit stuck here (i hope the example will show you the random function "stuck" after one click).

To start, I binded "body" + click to make things simplier :

http://jsfiddle.net/Hv8SD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array-shuffling algorithm is fully incorrect.
A can propose this variant:
var counter = 0, newArray = [];

```
while(counter < 147)
{
  var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*147 - 1)
  if(!newArray[randomnumber]) // if newArray doesn't contains index `randomnumber`
  {
    newArray[randomnumber]=arr[counter];
    counter++;
  };
};
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKAKq/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seemed to work but I did a little check to see if some array values are still repeated on the      $('#carac').html(newArray[index].Chinois); 
I ran a Jquery unique function with the generated content and shows that some index value are repeated with your function (about a 1/4th of the 147).

Comment: @Maikeximu jsfiddle demo is corrected. Please, look. New array is displayed to user with `alert` and values are not repeated

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I double checked what results would go out if i click 147 times on next/body in my document and then i sorted it out to see which "newArray[index].Numéro" (array number) are doubled or tripled. The result shows that some index is still repeated (and some index are missing).


1
2
2
2
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
10
12
12
14
16
18
19
19
20
21
22
23
23
24
26
27
29
29
31
32
33
33
34
35
36
39
39
39
40
40
41
41
42
43
43
43
43
45
45
49
49
49
50
50
52
53
54
54
54
57
57
58
58
60
61
62
62
64
64
69
69
71
72
72
73
73
74
75
78
78
81
82
83
84
(...)
// I stopped at 84 due to comment limits

Comment: I now understands why the index was repeating itself. I was because of the way the index was randomly chosen (with      index = Math.ceil(Math.random()*147);)instead of following the logical index = [index + 1]% arr.length. Thank you for your answer it made me realize how this logic works.